# Google Sheets "COUNTIF" function NOT showing multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a question about a google sheet formula?

=SUM(COUNTIF('Signed Case'!C:C,{"Barry","Maya"}))

It seems that Google Sheet can only count the total number of "Barry" but NOT BOTH "Barry" and "Maya", is there a way to fix this?

Greatly appreciated, thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change as

```
=sum(ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF('Signed Case'!C:C,{"Barry","Maya"})))
```

`ARRAYFORMULA` will develop countif for all criteria